# Rotate and scale an object with speed over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to scale and rotate an object. The rotation is on X-Axis. I am able to implement the scale perfectly, it is the rotation that is causing the problem. How do I rotate the object to a target rotation and then back to initial rotation with this script? When I am executing this script, the rotation sometimes work and sometimes does not execute, however there is no problem with the scaling.

EDIT: The basic thing I found was that I cannot set Quaternion to negative value, that is -90 becomes 270 automatically and due to this I cannot move 270 to 0.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
 public class ScaleAndRotate : MonoBehaviour { 
     public int startSize = 3;
     public int minSize = 1;
     public int maxSize = 6;
     
     public float speed = 2.0f;
     
     private Vector3 targetScale;
     private Vector3 baseScale;
     private int currScale;

     //ROT

     public Quaternion targetRotation;
     public bool startRotation = false;
     
     void Start() {
         baseScale = transform.localScale;
         transform.localScale = baseScale * startSize;
         currScale = startSize;
         targetScale = baseScale * startSize;
     }
     
     void Update() {
         transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp (transform.localScale, targetScale, speed * Time.deltaTime);

         if(startRotation == true)
         {
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
         }
         else
         if(startRotation == false)
         {
             //Go Back To Initial Rotation
         }
         
 
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))
         {
             ChangeSize (true);
             startRotation = true;
         }
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow))
         {
             ChangeSize (false);
             startRotation = false;
         }
     }
     
     public void ChangeSize(bool bigger) {
         
         if (bigger)
         {
             currScale++;
             
         }
             
         else
         {
             currScale--;
             
         }
             
         
         currScale = Mathf.Clamp (currScale, minSize, maxSize+1);
         
         targetScale = baseScale * currScale;
     }    
 }
```

Comment: `I cannot set Quaternion to negative value, that is -90 becomes 270 automatically and due to this I cannot move 270 to 0.` ... a `Quaternion` has four components `x, y, z, w` and they are all moving between `-1` and `1` ... so it is not really clear what you are talking about ... are you setting values via the Inspector?

Comment: Yes I was setting the values via the inspector.

Comment: @derHugo Could there be a different solution? Was waiting for your suggestion in this.

Comment: Well if your main issue was only `rotation` vs `localRotation` then this should be the answer already ;) ... not that using `Lerp` with a factor based on `Time.deltaTime` makes sense at all ... if you do this frame-wise starting from the current rotation towards a target you would rather either want a fix factor of e.g. `0.5f` or rather use something  [similar to SmoothDamp](https://answers.unity.com/questions/822852/quaternionlookrotation-and-vector3smoothdamp-probl.html)

Comment: Thanks I will try this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the `transform.rotation` that was not able to change the rotation from -90/270 to new rotation. I instead had to use `transform.localRotation` and it worked perfectly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
 public class ScaleAndRotate : MonoBehaviour { 
     public int startSize = 3;
     public int minSize = 1;
     public int maxSize = 6;
     
     public float speed = 2.0f;
     
     private Vector3 targetScale;
     private Vector3 baseScale;
     private int currScale;

     //ROT

     public Quaternion targetRotation;
     public Quaternion initialRotation;
     public bool startRotation = false;
     
     void Start() {
         baseScale = transform.localScale;
         transform.localScale = baseScale * startSize;
         currScale = startSize;
         targetScale = baseScale * startSize;

         initialRotation = transform.localRotation;
     }
     
     void Update() {
         transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp (transform.localScale, targetScale, speed * Time.deltaTime);

         if(startRotation == true)
         {
             transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
         }
         else
         if(startRotation == false)
         {
             //Go Back To Initial Rotation
             transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, initialRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
         }
         
 
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))
         {
             ChangeSize (true);
             startRotation = false;
         }
             
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow))
         {
             ChangeSize (false);
             startRotation = true;
         }
             
     }
     
     public void ChangeSize(bool bigger) {
         
         if (bigger)
         {
             currScale++;
             
         }
             
         else
         {
             currScale--;
             
         }
             
         
         currScale = Mathf.Clamp (currScale, minSize, maxSize+1);
         
         targetScale = baseScale * currScale;
     }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you miss brackets when you use `if` statements:

```
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))
             ChangeSize (true);
             startRotation = true;
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow))
             ChangeSize (false);
             startRotation = false;
```

When you use something like that code above the `if` is used only to the first following line of code. Thus, add brackets to that code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
             ChangeSize (true);
             startRotation = true;
}
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow))
{
             ChangeSize (false);
             startRotation = false;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I figured that later and changed it in my code, the rotation yet does not work. That is if the rotation is 270 and I want it to change to 0, it does not rotate, however it rotates from 0 to 270.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly set that public target quaternion? Maybe change it to `public Vector3 targetRotation` so it is in the euler angle now. Then, you can transform it to Quaternion using `Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation)`

Comment: The thing is i cannot change it to -90, it automatically changes to 270. And from 270 to 0 it somehow never runs.

Comment: Can you show how you initialize that `public Quaternion targetRotation;`?

Comment: ```public Quaternion targetRotation = (270, 0, 0)``` in the inspector window since -90 automatically changes to 270.

Comment: I found it! It was the localRotation that was causing the problem.

Comment: Btw, read this [https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html]. Don't init quaternion like that. I suggest to change it to `public Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);`

Comment: Yes I know, I meant in the inspector window, not in the script.